# How do I capture a customers email & name when using 'test_clock' in Stripe?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I need to ensure that my webhook will capture a customer's `name` and `email address` when subscription payments are made.

I thought I'd try out the `test_clock` feature offered by **Stripe** to simulate this.

The **Advance time** feature works perfectly because I can see that payments are deducted from the given card, however, I can't seem to be able to capture the **customer's email address** and **name** from the `event` response that is returned.

Find below my code that handles the `event.type`:

```
  // Handle the event

  switch (event.type) {
    case 'customer.subscription.updated': 
      console.log(`Subscription status updated: ${event.data.object.status}`);
      const subscription = event.data.object;
      const customerName = subscription.customer.name;
      const customerEmail = subscription.customer.email;

      console.log('customer Name is: ' + customerName);
      console.log('customer Email is: ' + customerEmail);
```

The code above yields:

```
Subscription status updated: active
customer Name is: undefined
customer Email is: undefined
```

How do I capture the customer's name and email address?

Comment: What does `console.log(event.data.object)` yield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [subscription object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-customer) (`event.data.object`), `customer` contains the customer ID which is a string instead of an object.

You need to fetch the customer details separately using the customer ID.

```js
// Handle the event
switch (event.type) {
  case 'customer.subscription.updated':
    console.log(`Subscription status updated: ${event.data.object.status}`);
    const subscription = event.data.object;
    const customerId = subscription.customer;
    
    // Fetch customer details using the customer ID
    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId);
    const customerName = customer.name;
    const customerEmail = customer.email;

    console.log('Customer Name is: ' + customerName);
    console.log('Customer Email is: ' + customerEmail);
    break;
}
```